# Creating thumbnails from video files with Python on my website

Tags: django, video

I need to create thumbnails for a video file which users uploaded to  web site running django.

How would I go about this...which function can do this ? I can display thumbnail images but I cant capture a view from a video. Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 2):

Videos are tricky business due to the vastness of codecs, containers, etc. I would recommend to use [`ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/) due to it's vast support and call it in Python using [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module. Following the [first](http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/29/creating-video-thumbnails-using-ffmpeg/) Google hit for `ffmpeg video thumbnail`, you can do it like:

```
from subprocess import check_output
check_output('ffmpeg  -itsoffset -4  -i test.avi -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 test.jpg', shell=True)
```

Obviously you have to change the command string but this should get you started.

Comment: How do I assign generated thumbnail image to an ImageField in one of the models.?

Comment: instantiate django's `File` object with the binary data of the image. You can pass that to model to save

Comment: This is what I tried but its not working.  
[link](http://pastebin.com/UpvBfkTS)

When i check img varialbe it says <File: None>. Any help? Same case when i instantiate with `ImageFile` object. :(